# How to destructure props in stateless component (react) with default values into a variable and apply spread operator with that variable in JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aframe, destructuring

The code below renders correctly

```
export default ({
  primitive = "a-sky",
  height = "2048",
  radius= "30",
  width= "2048"
}) => {
const properties = { primitive, height, radius, width}
return <Entity {...properties} />
}
```

However, is there something I can do to omit the need for duplicating the prop names *primitive, height, etc*?

The code below does not work but shows what I mean to accomplish

```
let properties
export default ({
  primitive = "a-sky",
  height = "2048",
  radius= "30",
  width= "2048"
} = properties) => {
return <Entity {...properties} />
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're trying to do is clever, but object destructuring doesn't allow you to strip properties while placing them in another object. However, you can spread the props into an object that you put defaults on, and return that object:

```
export default props => {
  const propsWithDefaults = {
    primitive: "a-sky",
    height: "2048",
    radius: "30",
    width: "2048",
    ...props
  };

  return <Entity {...propsWithDefaults} />
}
```

The properties in `props` will override the properties you hardcode in.

Edit: Another way which seems to be more of what you're looking for:

```
export default props => {
  const defaultProps = {
    primitive: "a-sky",
    height: "2048",
    radius: "30",
    width: "2048"
  };

  return <Entity {...Object.assign(defaultProps, props)} />
}
```

[Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) takes the first argument, and puts all properties of subsequent arguments on that first argument, overriding conflicts as it goes left to right. It then returns the 1st argument.

Comment: Thanks. That did it. It's unfortunate that we can't assign to another object at the same time but this solution is close enough. Guess we could also substitute the last line for `<Entity {...{...defaultParams, ...props}} />` but that may be less readable.

Comment: I edited my answer to add another way to do this. It seems to be closer to exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Ah. Yes. That's even better. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What data structure are you passing to this arrow function? Objects in javascript require `:` not `=` . If you're trying to declare default values such as the following notation:

```
( x = 'default for x', y = 'default for y' ) => {
    console.log(x, y);
}
```

Then remove the `{ }` from within the parameter portion of the arrow function.

Bringing it back to what you've posted though:

I'd recommend passing your arrow function a single object called `params` then use the spread operator on that.

```
((params) => <Entity {...params} />)({ a: "val", b: "val", c: "val"})
```